# fetch multiple mapped values from nested list using Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to get student names for respective universities where student id should be greater than 1 using java 8.
I am not able to get both university name and student name together as the output using map from java 8 as University has nested student list, i tried using below code but only able to fetch student name.
How can i map University name and student name together?

```
List<String> studentList =  uniList.stream().flatMap(x->x.getStudents().stream())
                                    .filter(stu->stu.getSid()>1)
                                    .map(student -> student.getName())
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have created Student and University pojo classes and Implementation Class.

```
Expected output is in below format:
University_name_1 : student_name_1, student_name_2, student_name_3 ...
University_name_2 : student_name_1, student_name_2, student_name_3 ...
```

University.java

```
public class University {

    private int uid;
    private String name;
    private List<Student> students;
    
    //getter and setter
}
```

Student.java

```
public class Student {

    private int sid;
    private String name;

    //getter and setter
}
```

Impl.java

```
public class Impl {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Student s1 = new Student(1, "Sam");
        Student s2 = new Student(1, "Daniel");

        List students = new ArrayList();
        students.add(s1);
        students.add(s2);

        University uni = new University();
        uni.setUid(1);
        uni.setName("AJIT");
        uni.setStudents(students);

        Student s3= new Student(2, "shahrukh");
        Student s4= new Student(2, "simran");

        List students1 = new ArrayList();
        students1.add(s3);
        students1.add(s4);

        University uni2 = new University();
        uni2.setUid(2);
        uni2.setName("NJIT");
        uni2.setStudents(students1);

        List<University> uniList = new ArrayList();
        uniList.add(uni);
        uniList.add(uni2);
        
        List<String> studentList =  uniList.stream().flatMap(x->x.getStudents().stream())
                                    .filter(stu->stu.getSid()>1)
                                    .map(student -> student.getName())
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        System.out.println(studentList);

    }

}
```

Comment: Look into Collectors.groupingBy.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `Map<String, List<String>>` instead of a `List<String>`.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = 
    uniList.stream()                        
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        University::getName, 
                        u -> u.getStudents()
                                  .stream()
                                  .filter(s -> s.getSid() > 1)
                                  .map(Student::getName)
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList())
                    )
            );

System.out.println(map);
```

**Output:**

```
{NJIT=[shahrukh, simran], AJIT=[]}
```

Also, do not use raw type (e.g. `List students = new ArrayList()`); use generic type (e.g. `List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>()`) instead.

Comment: The OP wanted to also filter the students ID to be greater than 1. However, I don’t understand how an ID could be less than 1, but I’m wondering if your post accomplishes what OP wanted

Comment: `.filter(stu->stu.getSid()>1)` in the question, doesn't look like the same filter in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = uniList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
            key::getName, 
            value -> value.getStudents()
                          .stream()
                          .filter(student -> student.getId() > 1)
                          .map(student -> student.getName())
                          .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```